# Validate that URI is not empty in RelaxNG

Tags: validation, xsd, uri, relaxng

I'm trying to validate that an element always has an href attribute in RelaxNG, and assumed you could do it with this:

```
<attribute name="href">
  <data type="anyURI"/>
</attribute>
```

Only catch is, apparently [anyURI considers empty strings to be valid](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xml-dist-app/2003Mar/0076.html), so `href=""` passes with flying colors.  Is there any easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `minLength` facet. For example:

```
<attribute name="href">
  <data type="anyURI">
    <param name="minLength">5</param>
  </data>
</attribute>
```

See also http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#anyURI